# Wordpress multisite error 404 on Network Admin and other links

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

Hi I have a fresh install of Wordpress in my domain, configured for multi-site. Subfolder setup.

the thing is, Network Admin on the upper right menu has this link http://example.net/wp-admin/network/ and returns error 404... I can manually type it to http://example.net/subfolder/wp-admin/network/ and works fine.. other links like Add New has this problem too...

I'm not good on .htaccess but I think the problem is there...

can you check this please

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) home/content/70/10156275/html/example.net/subfolder/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ home/content/70/10156275/html/example.net/subfolder/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

also, not sure if this helps but my wp-config.php has this

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.net' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

been searching google for 2 days now and can't fix this...
The problem is the subfolder is somewhat omitted in Network Admin and some few..

Comment: According to this rule: `RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]`, all URIs that have `wp-admin` are mapped to `wp-admin/`. ¿Have you tried removing this rule?

Comment: Is it a subfolder or subdomain installation? There are two extra  lines in your `.htaccess` from what I see in my `/wp-admin/network/setup.php` subdomain setup. And the `#uploaded files` line is missing.

Comment: that .htaccess is what the installation gave me..

Comment: I think you need to let WP know it is installed in a subfolder. My guess would be that `define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );` should be `define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/subfolder' );`. I never worked with WP though, but incorrect html links have nothing to do with htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to help you and let you know that you need to set `define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );`

and not

```
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
```

,if you are using subfolder setup (and not subdomain). This may as well solve your problem.